# How to convert a JSON to XML using groovy?

Tags: xml, json, groovy

I am tyring to convert

```
jsonOutput ="{"id":"108013515952807","posts":{"data":[{"id":"108013515952807_470186843068804","created_time":"2013-05-14T20:43:28+0000"},{"message":"TEKST","id":"108013515952807_470178529736302","created_time":"2013-05-14T20:22:07+0000"}";
```

To XML Format using Groovy?

Comment: What has been tried yet?

Comment: This is an invalid json string.

Comment: What do you expect your XML to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The json string is not valid as you have it, but assuming it is fixed, then you can do something like this:

```
def jsonOutput = '{"id":"108013515952807","posts":{"data":[{"id":"108013515952807_470186843068804","created_time":"2013-05-14T20:43:28+0000"},{"message":"TEKST","id":"108013515952807_470178529736302","created_time":"2013-05-14T20:22:07+0000"}]}}'
def parsed = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonOutput)
def sw = new StringWriter()
new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(sw).with {
  doubleQuotes = true
  visitor = { k, v ->
    "$k" { v instanceof Map ? v.collect(visitor) : v instanceof Collection ? v.eachWithIndex { item,i -> "$i"(item.id, item) } : mkp.yield(v) }
  }
  data(type: 'current') { parsed.collect visitor }
}

println sw.toString()
```

Which will produce the following:

```
<data type="current">
  <id>108013515952807</id>
  <posts>
    <data>
      <0 id="108013515952807_470186843068804" created_time="2013-05-14T20:43:28+0000">108013515952807_470186843068804</0>
      <1 id="108013515952807_470178529736302" message="TEKST" created_time="2013-05-14T20:22:07+0000">108013515952807_470178529736302</1>
    </data>
  </posts>
</data>
```

Hopefully that will give you something to work with...